# Binding routes to wrong method controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 app. I
have the bellow routes:

```
Route::get('{thing}', 'DisplayController@showThingNewRoute');
Route::get('{about}', 'DisplayController@showAboutNewRoute');
```

Also I use RouteServiceProvider like so:

```
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {

    parent::boot($router);

    $router->bind('thing', function($thing){ 
       return \App\Thing::publish()->where('seo_url', '=', $thing)->first(); 
   }); 

    $router->bind('about', function($about){ 
       return \App\About::publish()->where('seo_url', '=', $about)->firstOrFail(); 
    });    

    }
```

The problem is that I can't have a route to execute with a second method `showAboutNewRoute`

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Because these 2 routes share same URL signature. Laravel finds one, it satisfies the condition of URL and it executes the method.

Answer (score 2):

Your both route share the same url, whatever you are putting inside curly braces it is like a variable.

You can define your route like this

```
Route::get('thing/{thing}', 'DisplayController@showThingNewRoute');
Route::get('about/{about}', 'DisplayController@showAboutNewRoute');
```

Otherwise whatever you will put after your domain, it will pick as first route unless you define any string as a first argument of get method.

Comment: @amrfs then how do you expect laravel to route to the correct controller method?

Answer (score 0):

Your routes have the same URL, the access conditions are the same. For laravel if you put one string next to the root URL you access both of the routes.

You need to disambiguate the routes like this for example :

```
Route::get('thing/{thing}', 'DisplayController@showThingNewRoute');
Route::get('about/{about}', 'DisplayController@showAboutNewRoute');
```